# If the answer to question B answers question A, should question A be considered a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

The question
[Fields and proper subfields.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633448/fields-and-proper-subfields/633469#633469),
which asks if a field can be isomorphic to a proper subfield was closed as a duplicate of
[Algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137906/algebraic-closure-of-mathbbcx-is-isomorphic-to-mathbbc).

Ofcourse, (the answer to) the second question answers the first, but I don't think this should be considered a duplicate (at least not of the second one). In particular, someone coming up with this question when starting to study fields, might not even recognize that the second question gives an answer.

Edit: I realize that the general question in the title is likely unanswerable (other than "maybe; depends on the questions"). My concern is actually with the specific questions.

Comment: This seems (to some extent) related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6941/handling-near-duplicates (I guess you will find more related questions here on meta.)

Comment: I realize that the general question in the title is likely unanswerable (other than "maybe; depends on the questions"). My concern is actually with the specific questions in the body.

Comment: Magdiragdag: If you want to ask about one particular instance (rather than discuss the question in general) you should also add ([meta-tag:specific-question]) tag to indicate this. (See the [tag-wiki](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-question/info) for more information about this tag.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ok, thanks. I'll do so.

Comment: As long as the closed question is *not deleted*, the next person asking the same thing has a chance of finding it.  Note: in my opinion, closed questions should, in many cases, *not* be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The question boils down to whether a user asking a question can reasonably be assumed to be able to apply the answer to another question to their own problem. This is easier to judge if the question comes with information on the background of the user, own atempts, where the question comes from, etc.

If a user doesn't provide such information, it is partially the users own fault if a question is marked as a duplicate. Of course, the user can still edit the question and clarify the question and its background so much that it is clear that it should not be duplicate.

**Edit:** It is of course also possible to simply ask the user in a comment whether they know about the connecting facts. I think it also okay to explain in a comment how the answer to the more general answer question answers the special case when closing as a duplicate.